# Percentage of false postive in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

Does anyone know an algorithms that I can use to calculate the percentage of false positive in a two column list.

Take my situation for instance . I have a clustering vector showing me groups a cluster belongs to and I have the correct label by the side on another column. I know some classifications are wrong from them not mapping to their labels which is most occurring. How can I finding the percentage of false positive for all labels . I am implementing this in R.

```
Cluster_vector   |    Labels
        1              5     
        3              5
        1              5
        1              5
        6              5
```

Comment: You may want to expand your perspective to include getting a confusion matrix out of this.

Comment: You really ought to include an example for which the "false positive" result is not undefined. How can you calculate a FP for being in "5" when there are no predicted "5"'s? You should also clarify which of these columns represent "truth" or "gold-standard". At the moment I cannot tell for sure. I would assume it is "Labels" given R coding conventions, but your text makes me wonder if that is how you see it.

Comment: thanks the Labels represent the gold standard and I have collected them myself. But you know how clusters vectors are in R  you cannot get the same numbers as my labels .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you just looking for the proportion of mismatches, like `mean(x[,1] != x[,2])`?

You can get the confusion matrix by `table(x[,1] != x[,2])/nrow(x)`.